# not able to display a textfield or button on extjs tree node

Tags: extjs, treenode

I have an extjs tree. I can add tree nodes dynamically to the selected node. But to the newly added node I need a textfield too attached with it.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98CRT.png)

Comment: Ok. What did you try? Where's your code?

Comment: can you please provide sencha fiddle so I can check the issue?

Comment: Which ExtJS version do you use? Have you had a look at [`widgetcolumn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html)?

Comment: Dont know where to start the code .I have a tree panel as on the screenshot attached,without textfield or button.On search i couldn't find any sample to have a try.iam using extjs 6.